# How can i configure my custom s3 putevent that triggers AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iot

It would be very much help full if someone might walk me through this, i Have tried going through event structure but was not that helpful !

[Aws lambda Event structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure)

I am still not abel to understand Many of u attended the question its grate full, but yet im not able to understand you, I'am completly new to aws.

I went through the event structure, it says you will find the configuration id over here
"configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration"
but i could not

and I'am still clue less about

> "x-amz-request-id":"Amazon S3 generated request ID",
>
> "x-amz-id-2":"Amazon S3 host that processed the request"

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
from decimal import Decimal
import json
import urllib

print('Loading function')

rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
iot = boto3.client('iot-data')


# --------------- Helper Functions to call Rekognition APIs ------------------

def compare_faces(bucket, key, key_target, threshold=90):
    response = rekognition.compare_faces(
        SourceImage={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": 'dacsup',
                "Name": 'obama.jpg',
            }
        },
        TargetImage={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": 'targetts',
                "Name": 'obama2.jpg',
            }
        },
        SimilarityThreshold=threshold,
    )
    return response['SourceImageFace'], response['FaceMatches']

# --------------- Main handler ------------------


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
    key_target = "targetts/" + key
    try:
        response = compare_faces(bucket, key, key_target)
        print(response)
        mypayload = json.dumps(response)
        iotResponse = iot.publish(
            topic="rekognition/result",
            qos=1,
            payload=mypayload)
        print(iotResponse)
        return iotResponse
        print(response)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Error processing object {} from bucket {}. ".format(key, bucket) +
              "Make sure your object and bucket exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.")
        raise e
```

-----------------------event------------------

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventTime": "2019-02-08T11:49:26.471Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "My ip"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "----------------",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "99b7ce351fec8c0e7b30fd194a8c81b3",
          "sequencer": "-----------",
          "key": "obama.jpg",
          "size": 5908
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "  arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
          "name": " dacsup ",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "Mypprincipalid"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "-------------",
        "x-amz-request-id": "-----------"
      },
      "awsRegion": " us-east-2",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "myrincipalid"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```

error----------------------------xxxxxxxxx------------------------

```
START RequestId: 24820efa-d454-4ae4-9c49-e2eedd1c96ce Version: $LATEST
Received event: {
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1", 
      "eventTime": "2019-03-04T11:49:26.471Z", 
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "My ip"
      }, 
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "", 
        "object": {
          "eTag": "99b7ce351fec8c0e7b30fd194a8c81b3 ", 
          "key": "obama.jpg", 
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901 ", 
          "size": 5908
        }, 
        "bucket": {
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "My pid"
          }, 
          "name": " dacsup ", 
          "arn": "  arn:aws:s3:::dacsup "
        }, 
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      }, 
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "", 
        "x-amz-request-id": ""
      }, 
      "awsRegion": " us-east-2", 
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put", 
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "pid"
      }, 
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
Error processing object obama.jpg from bucket . Make sure your object and bucket exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.
An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.: InvalidS3ObjectException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 59, in lambda_handler
    raise e
InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.

END RequestId: 24820efa-d454-4ae4-9c49-e2eedd1c96ce
REPORT RequestId: 24820efa-d454-4ae4-9c49-e2eedd1c96ce  Duration: 372.53 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB
```

Comment: Originally, you asked how to *retrieve* the attributes, and it was unclear what you are asking -- the solution for the other attributes is exactly as you have shown for `bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']`...  So, it appears that you know how to retrieve them.  Are you saying you need help *understanding the purpose* of these attributes?

Comment: no i want those attributes can u tell me where i can find them@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: `event['Records'][0]['responseElements']['x-amz-request-id']` and `event['Records'][0]['responseElements']['x-amz-id-2']` and `event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['configurationId']`

Comment: I have mentioned the lambda function and the above event triggers this function problem is this, i don't know the x-amz-request-id, x-amz-id-2. where can i find this or i have to use a tool or separate code to find the values@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: My previous comment gives you exactly the expressions that will extract these values from the event structure.  
 If that does not answer your question, then it is still not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: it was not that specific and the other thing is where should i use it@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: if i say i don't know the values and want those values then? the thing is i am not having this values that's why the function throws an error@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Is this a fake S3 event notification that you are trying to generate, as a test?  There are many problems with the data shown, including spaces inside quotes, and those are the problem -- not the other missing values, which are not needed.  For example, in `"name": " dacsup ",` the value has a stray space at the beginning and end of the string, inside the quotes.

Comment: its not an fake notification as such, but ya i am trying to test it in the console it self. And if the quotes i guess that's an issue ill updated it. But just for information will the responseElements play a role init or not?@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: i tried removing the spaces had no effect the issue persist@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Those elements will make no difference for this purpose.  The error seems to clearly indicate that the problem is related to the bucket name, and the stray whitespace inside the quotes is absolutely invalid.  On a new line, right before `response = compare_faces(bucket, key, key_target)` please log the values of bucket, key, and key_target and verify that the values are all present and do not have any incorrect whitespace within the strings.

Comment: it worked out fine. i mean there are no errors now but when using the event with iot which is my actual application will the requestElements play a role?

Comment: No, they won't.  Those values are generated by the system, for correlation and troubleshooting purposes.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-id-values/

Comment: can u ans some thing on the post so that i can accept it an close the query

Answer (score 1):

This is the current version of [Event message structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html). All the fields you've mentioned are available here.

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.1",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
         "eventTime":The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, when Amazon S3 finished processing the request,
         "eventName":"event-type",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-user-who-caused-the-event"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"ip-address-where-request-came-from"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"Amazon S3 generated request ID",
            "x-amz-id-2":"Amazon S3 host that processed the request"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-bucket-owner"
               },
               "arn":"bucket-ARN"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
               "size":object-size,
               "eTag":"object eTag",
               "versionId":"object version if bucket is versioning-enabled, otherwise null",
               "sequencer": "a string representation of a hexadecimal value used to determine event sequence, 
                   only used with PUTs and DELETEs"
            }
         },
         "glacierEventData": {
            "restoreEventData": {
               "lifecycleRestorationExpiryTime": "The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, of Restore Expiry",
               "lifecycleRestoreStorageClass": "Source storage class for restore"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: i have gone through this but i am not able to retrieve those attributes @A.Khan

Comment: please supply code that you are using to retrieve those attributes.

Comment: im using browsers developer tool to capture the attributes@A.Khan

Comment: @PratikDesai this event structure is sent to the Lambda function invocation, not the browser, so it is unclear why or how you would be using the browser developer tools to view this.  All of the properties you mentioned are clearly visble in the structure, so it is difficult to understand why you would not be able to retrieve these.  If you don't see an object similar to what is shown here, you'll need to edit your question to show us what you are seeing instead, and the code you are using, as was mentioned already.

Comment: i have edited some more details but the question remains same though @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: i want to configure my custom event that triggers my lambda, the problem is im not able to figure out the values for response headers x-amz-request-id and so on @A.Khan